# How to get the translated text from google translator using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

I have tried the following code to get the google translator text using selenium:

```
result=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='result_box']/span"));
```

I also tried these:

```
1.result=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//body/div[@id='result_box']/span"));
2.result=driver.findElement(By.xpath("./*div[@id='result_box']/span"));
3.result=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@id='result_box']/span"));
4.result=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='result_box']/span"));
5.result=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//body/div[@id='result_box']/span"));
6.result=driver.findElement(By.xpath("./*[@id='result_box']/span"));
```

But none of the above works. I then tried to get the text by:

```
result=driver.findElement(By.id("result_box")).findElement(By.tagName("span")); 
translatedtext=result.getText();
```

This returns a result but when I try to show the result in JTextarea it shows me '????' instead of the actual translated text.

I have also tried 'result.getAttribute("innerHTML")' but it also shows some question marks (?????) instead of the original translated text in JTextarea.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result box has tag `<span>`, not `<div>`

```
result = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@id='result_box']/span"));
```

Or

```
result = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='result_box']/span"));
```

With double slash.

Answer (score 1):

you also can use css selector like this:

result = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#result_box>span"));

people say that is faster than xpath

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, however i used python,you can try using equivalent of `find_element_by_id` function in Java

```
driver.find_element_by_id("gt-res-dir-ctr").text
```